# "Lock & Erase" feature on my android phone

Tags: android-device-manager

I lost my android phone and tried using Android Device Manager.  Normally when you got to Android Device Manage it gives you three choices:  "Ring", "Lock", and "Erase".
For some reason, on the phone that I am looking for, it only gives you two choices:  "Ring" and "Lock & Erase".  Here are my questions:
1.  If I select "Lock & Erase", will it give me a choice between the two?
2.  If I select "Lock & Erase", and it doesn't give me a choice will it ask me "Are you sure" before proceeding?
3.  If the Android Device Manage "erases" and puts the phone back to factory default, will the "finder" of my phone be able to re-activate the phone?
Thanks!

Comment: About that third point: see  what is the meaning of [tag:factory-reset]?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include a screenshot of what you see on Android Device Manager?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Device Manager is only able to work if:

1 .You enabled it on your phone.
2. Your phone has an active connection to the internet.
3. At the time its connected to the internet, your google account is still signed into the phone. If your finder performs a hard reset on your phone or resets it to factory default settings, your google account is erased effectively rendering ring lock or erase useless.
Are you using a web browser to access the ring lock and erase feature?